# How to access Boa Constructor IDE

Tags: user-interface, ide, boa

Hi I know you all probably think I'm thick but, how do I actualy access the boa constructor IDE to build a gui?  I have downloaded it and added it to python 2.7.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would run (click on, if Windows) the file named Boa.py that is located in the boa-constructor folder. It might be here:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boa-constructor\Boa.py
```

That will start the application. I think there are some tweaks you might have to make to run Boa 0.6.1 well with Python 2.7, but it can be done. Let me know if you need further help.